# Warning ASP5001 'MvcCoreMvcBuilderExtensions.SetCompatibilityVersion(IMvcBuilder, CompatibilityVersion)' is obsolete

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nuget-package

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I installed this NuGet package:

```
<PackageReference Include="microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.versioning.apiexplorer" Version="5.0.0" />

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace WebApi.API.V1
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    internal static class ApiStartup
    {
        public static void AddMyApi(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHealthChecks();
            services.AddControllers()
                .AddControllersAsServices()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
                .AddJsonOptions(c =>
                    c.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy
                        = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase);
        }
    }
}
```

I got these errors:

> Warning   ASP5001 'CompatibilityVersion' is obsolete: 'This API is obsolete and will be removed in a future version. Consider removing usages.'

> Warning   CS0618  'CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0' is obsolete: 'This CompatibilityVersion value is obsolete.'

> Warning   ASP5001 'MvcCoreMvcBuilderExtensions.SetCompatibilityVersion(IMvcBuilder, CompatibilityVersion)' is obsolete: 'This API is obsolete and will be removed in a future version. Consider removing usages.'

How do resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using the appropriate compatibility switches:
Allows you to use the latest release and opt out of specific breaking behavior changes.

With ASP.NET Core 3.0, old behaviors supported by compatibility switches have been removed.

And I think, you upgraded to .Net 6 so you can remove this SetCompatibilityVersion, there is no need of this.